# SQL Server query troubles, many-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure how to word this question in one line, apologies for the title...

I have 3 tables in my database, for example:

- Shop
- Item
- ShopStock

Shop and Item have a many-many relationship and so the ShopStock table links them.

The fields in ShopStock are:

- ID
- ShopID
- ItemID
- CurrentStock

I want to list the items, showing how much stock each shop has, but I'm having trouble with the SQL.  Something like this:

```
ITEM   TESCO STOCK   ASDA STOCK   SAINSBURY STOCK
Apples 5             20           74
Pears  1000          32           250
```

How do I build the SQL query to display the data like this?

Comment: If you want to structure the result set like that, try using `PIVOT`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier to list as item,shop,currentstock in multiple rows.  As is, unless you know the number of shops, you're going to need to use dynamic sql for this.  If you know the number of potential shops, you can use `PIVOT` to return your results.

Something like this assuming you had 2 shops (shop1 and shop2):

```
select item_name, [Shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  select item_name, shop_name, currentstock
  from item i
  join shopstock ss on i.item_id = ss.item_id 
  join shop s on s.shop_id = ss.shop_id
) x
pivot 
(
  max(currentstock)
  for shop_name in ([Shop1],[Shop2])
) p
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66e41/2)

Here is the dynamic sql approach as I suspect you don't know the number of possible shops:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(shop_name) 
                    from shop
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select item_name,' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
                select item_name, shop_name, currentstock
                from item i
                  join shopstock ss on i.item_id = ss.item_id 
                  join shop s on s.shop_id = ss.shop_id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(currentstock)
                for shop_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66e41/1)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add JOINS to get specific names, but this is the idea you're after:

```
SELECT ItemID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ShopID = 'Tesco' THEN CurrentStock ELSE 0 END)'Tesco Stock'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ShopID = 'ASDA' THEN CurrentStock ELSE 0 END)'ASDA Stock'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ShopID = 'Sainsbury' THEN CurrentStock ELSE 0 END)'SainsburyStock'
FROM ShopStock 
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Assuming one entry per item per shopID. If there are multiples then you would have to SUM() them, but the idea is the same.