# SQL Combining Multiple Tables and Pivotting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these tables

```
Student - studentID, batchID, courseID, FirstName, Last Name ...
Subject - subjectID, courseID, subjectName ...
Mark - markID, studentID, subjectID, Marks
Course - courseID, courseName ...
```

I have been trying this for so long and finally ended up with this...

```
SELECT S.studentID AS 'ID', S.FirstName + ' ' + S.LastName AS 'Full Name', M.Marks AS 'Subject'
FROM Student AS S
LEFT JOIN Mark AS M ON S.studentID = M.studentID AND M.subjectID = 'S1001'
WHERE S.batchID = 1
```

This one only shows the data for only one subject and the subject name is being generated by C# (Winforms) using the subjectID.

```
Student ID | Full Name    | Elementary Programming in C
-------------------------------------------------------
    1      | student name |        50
    2      | abc          |        80
```

but I want it to show all the subjects in that course and the respective marks in that column, like this (don't mind if i have to generate column headers using Winforms if subjectID is given)...

```
Student ID | Full Name    | Elementary Programming in C | HTML | ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    1      | student name |        50                   |  70  | ...
    2      | abc          |        80                   |  60  | ...
```

I have tried using pivot, but it wasn't very successful...
Hope someone can give me an idea or two, and if you need more information just ask...

Comment: Do you know the number of courses or is it dynamic per student?

Comment: @sgeddes The student can only participate in 1 course so only 1 course.

Comment: I meant do you have a predefined number of expected columns or is that dynamic per result. If you know the columns in advanced (i.e. Elementary programming, html, c#, sql, etc.), then you can construct a `pivot` table pretty easily or use `max` with `case`.  If you have a dynamic set of columns, then you'll have to create a `dynamic sql` statement.

Comment: @sgeddes : For every course there are different amount of subjects in it, so for example if the course is Diploma in Software Engineering, it has subjects like HTML and C# while multimedia courses have other subjects like CorelDraw

Comment: See if this doesn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16946945/1073631

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks, I got an idea on how to do this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
select @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(subjectName) 
                from Subject WHERE courseID = 'C1001'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select studentID,' + @cols + '
         from 
         (
            select S.studentID, ss.subjectID, M.Marks
            from Student S
              join Subject ss on S.courseID = ss.courseID 
              join Mark M on M.subjectID = ss.SubjectID AND M.studentID = S.StudentID
            where S.batchID = 1
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(Marks)
            for subjectName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```